# .h1 .h2 .h3 .h4 .h5 .h6 classes in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, font-size

Is it good practice to use `.h1 .h2 .h3 .h4 .h5 .h6` Bootstrap classes, for paragraphs of text? (Not headings).

For example:

```
<h1>THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
<p class="h5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<h2>THIS IS A SUB TITLE</h2>
<p class="h6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

If this is not the correct way, how can I use different font sizes using Bootstrap? (not headings)

Answer (score 3):

As Jakub mentioned from bootstrap docs:

> .h1 through .h6 classes are also available, for when you want to match the font styling of a heading but cannot use the associated HTML element.

In addition, Well think of **SEO**, here are some good practices:

> Heading tags have some influence when it comes to ranking in Google

> Stick to one ‘H1’ on the page, and make the rest of the text headings ‘H2’, ‘H3′. Keep headings in order

Now you want to let an element be the same size as h1,h2, or h3. For instance, you want a `<span>` element to be the same size as h1 but you don't want to break the rule `Stick to one H1 on the page` you use a class.

Another example you are adding header groups in order and you want to break that order, then you use a class.

Answer (score 1):

According to Bootstrap Docs you can do that.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/typography/#headings

> `.h1` through `.h6` classes are also available, for when you want to match the font styling of a heading but cannot use the associated HTML element.

If you don't want to use `<p>` tags you can always use `<div class="h1">`.

---

You can always set your own size using CSS.

For example:

```
.myClass{
    font-size:2rem;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:1.5;
    margin-bottom:1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 4.5.0, you can use class of display to change the font sizes of your desired output.

```
<h1 class="display-1"> Hello World </h1>
<h1 class="display-2"> Hello World </h1>
<h1 class="display-3"> Hello World </h1>
<h1 class="display-4"> Hello World </h1>
<h1 class="display-5"> Hello World </h1>
```

You can try any of these and for more information visit Bootstrap Docs > Typography
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/

Answer (score 0):

Is it good practice? **No.**
Is it bad practice? **No.**

If you want to develop a web page that complies with W3 specification, a good practice would be using heading tags correctly.

The Bootstrap classes you mentioned are just classes to help you style your elements to look better.

---

> **Usage notes**
>
> - Heading information may be used by user agents, for example, to construct a table of contents for a document automatically.
> - Avoid using heading tags to resize text. Instead, use the CSS font-size property. Headings use size to indicate their relative importance, but CSS is preferred for general-purpose resizing.
> - Avoid skipping heading levels: always start from , next use  and so on.
> - You should only use one  per page. Using more than one will not result in an error, but using only one is seen as a best practice. It makes logical sense —  is the most important heading, and tells you what the purpose of the overall page is. You wouldn't have a book with more than one title, or a movie with more than one name! Having a single top-level title is also arguably better for screenreader users, and SEO.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements